# OSX Sierra: Mail Rules gone

Tags: macos, mail-rules

Just went add a mail rule and it appears that the sierra upgrade has wiped all mail rules:

[image]

Is there any way to recover them, or do I need to set them all up again?
Staggers me that apple still can't get this right...